# Create Time Picker on Flutter with Specific Style

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

How do we create a time picker with this style and this kind of color?

[image]

The standard `showTimePicker` function produced a very ugly time picker.

[image]

P.S.: I'd like to do this without external package

Comment: These packages will help you with what you are trying to achieve:-1. https://pub.dev/packages/date_time_picker 2. https://pub.dev/packages/datetime_picker_formfield